# How are the different derivations of Bell's inequality related?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, bells-inequality, non-locality

I wanted to ask  about two different derivations for bell's inequality for the known CHSH inequality.
One  derivation is the one bell originally used  in 1971
this derivation is thoroughly written in the following link

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CHSH_inequality

another much simpler derivation i ran into is mentioned in this link

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell%27s_theorem#cite_note-mike-and-ike-9

and is referenced  to the following  book:

Nielsen, Michael A.; Chuang, Isaac L. (2010). Quantum Computation and Quantum Information (2nd ed.). Cambridge: Cambridge University Press.

How come the bell derivation is so cumbersome while the second one is much simpler?
Does the second derivation makes some different or Mitigating conditions?

Comment: I don't have access to the specific book you posted, but as a general comment, it is very common for an original and important mathematical argument to be simplified over time as people digest it and rederive the result in different ways. Once you know it's *possible* to find a route from A to B, it becomes worth the effort to look for the *most efficient* way to get there.

Comment: Bell's inequality is a set-theoretic result. There are different ways of putting it down. The most vivid for me is the GZH-Mermin form. Set up a clever game that is not winnable with only local processing, then show that something violates this. "With local hidden variables the highest probability of victory they can have is 3/4, whereas using the quantum strategy above they win it with certainty. This is an example of quantum pseudo-telepathy." (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell%27s_theorem)

Comment: The solution in the book is largely copied in the Wikipedia article.

Comment: Are you asking about the proof of Bell's inequalities in chapter 2 of Nielsen&Chuang? It is a simplified version. Wikipedia's seems to provide a more general proof.

Comment: Yes,Is it simpler but ignore some edge cases? or is it as legitimate as bell's original proof?

Comment: the original formulation by Bell was a bit different to what is meant/used today when talking about "Bell's nonlocality" or "Bell's inequalities". I believe there were some caveats and/or unnecessary complications in the original formulation which were ironed out later. Unless you're interested in it for historical reasons, I'd just consider the modern approach (essentially the CHSH versions, and generalisations thereof)